# kable showing html code instead of html table

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra, rnotebook

I was trying to use kable to generate a beautiful table. However, kable just returned the html code instead of the table itself in r notebook (R version 3.5.0, R Version 1.1.453 on a Mac).

## Test 1

````
```{r}
library(knitr)
dt <- mtcars[1:5,1:6]
knitr::kable(dt)  
```
````

Results shown in the R Notebook interface and the .html document:

```
|                  |  mpg| cyl| disp|  hp| drat|    wt|
|:-----------------|----:|---:|----:|---:|----:|-----:|
|Mazda RX4         | 21.0|   6|  160| 110| 3.90| 2.620|
|Mazda RX4 Wag     | 21.0|   6|  160| 110| 3.90| 2.875|
|Datsun 710        | 22.8|   4|  108|  93| 3.85| 2.320|
|Hornet 4 Drive    | 21.4|   6|  258| 110| 3.08| 3.215|
|Hornet Sportabout | 18.7|   8|  360| 175| 3.15| 3.440|
```

## Test2

```
library(knitr)
dt <- mtcars[1:5,1:6]
knitr::kable(dt, format = "html")
```

Results shown in the R Notebook interface and the .html document:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="text-align:left;">   </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> mpg </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> cyl </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> disp </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> hp </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> drat </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> wt </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> Mazda RX4 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 21.0 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 6 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 160 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 110 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.90 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 2.620 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> Mazda RX4 Wag </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 21.0 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 6 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 160 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 110 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.90 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 2.875 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> Datsun 710 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 22.8 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 4 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 108 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 93 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.85 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 2.320 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> Hornet 4 Drive </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 21.4 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 6 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 258 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 110 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.08 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.215 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> Hornet Sportabout </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 18.7 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 8 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 360 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 175 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.15 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.440 </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

## Test 3

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:5,1:6]
kable(dt, format = "html")
```

Results: Same as above

As the output in the .html document also showed the raw html code above instead of the html table, is it a bug of this version of kable/r notebook?

Update:
After adding `results = 'asis'` in the chunk options, the output is successfully rendered into the .html document. However, I still could't see it the rnotebook. Is there any way I could see it in RNotebook? Thanks.

````
```{r results = "asis"}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:5,1:6]
kable(dt, format = "html")
```
````

.html document screen capture
[image: .html document screen capture]

What is shown in the R Notebook document

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="text-align:left;">   </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> mpg </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> cyl </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> disp </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> hp </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> drat </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> wt </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> Mazda RX4 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 21.0 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 6 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 160 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 110 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.90 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 2.620 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> Mazda RX4 Wag </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 21.0 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 6 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 160 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 110 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.90 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 2.875 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> Datsun 710 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 22.8 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 4 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 108 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 93 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.85 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 2.320 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> Hornet 4 Drive </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 21.4 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 6 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 258 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 110 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.08 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.215 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> Hornet Sportabout </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 18.7 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 8 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 360 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 175 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.15 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.440 </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Try the chunk option `results = "asis"`.

Comment: Thx @MartinSchmelzer. I tried it and the output is successfully rendered into the html document. However, I still could't see it the rnotebook. Is it the limitation of rnotebook? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried not defining any format?

Comment: @PedroSchuller What do you mean by defining the format? Thanks.

Comment: I mean ommiting the `format = "html"` parameter you pass to kable().

Comment: @PedroSchuller Yes, I have tried that. But it returned the html code regardless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to pipe the result to `kable_styling`. It will apply a print method so the table will be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

or you could use the 'pipe' format of kable() `knitr::kable(., format = "pipe", padding = 2)`